# nginx: Pointing Zabbix web panel address to specific path

Tags: nginx, webserver, zabbix

I'm trying to point Zabbix's web frontend page to serve from `http://<host>/zabbix` web page. It's serving from `http://<host>/` by default, however, `/` can serve to another web sites projects later.

I want to all related stuff of Zabbix must serve from `/zabbix` subpath and it's subpaths.
This is Zabbix's default nginx configuration file, nearly same as default.

```
server {
        listen          8080;
        server_name     localhost;

        root    /usr/share/zabbix;

        index   index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found   off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files       $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /assets {
                access_log      off;
                expires         10d;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny            all;
        }

        location ~ /(api\/|conf[^\.]|include|locale) {
                deny            all;
                return          404;
        }

        location /vendor {
                deny            all;
                return          404;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php-fpm/zabbix.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;

                fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /usr/share/zabbix;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
                fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
                fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
                fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;

                fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout         60;
                fastcgi_send_timeout            180;
                fastcgi_read_timeout            180;
                fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
                fastcgi_buffers                 4 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
        }
```

I tried changing location / { ... } block to location /zabbix { ... }, but nothing happened. Zabbix was still serving from "/" web page. Also I tried adding zabbix to all location definitions after "/"

I also tried that changing "location /" block to that

```
location / {
               return 403;
        }
```

Then I added a block as:

```
location /zabbix {
                try_files       $uri $uri/ index.php;
        }
```

This was working when you want to access to `http://<host>/zabbix` web page, and blocks requests to `/`, but when you logon to Zabbix web panel, it returns to `http://<host>/index.php`, which I want to serve like `http://<host>/zabbix/index.php` for all Zabbix related pages.

Comment: So adding the last location block worked, but after login you got redirected to `http://<host>/index.php` instead of `http://<host>/zabbix/index.php`, is that correct? Did you login and after the wrong redirect manually typed in the `http://<host>/zabbix/index.php`, to try if you can access it on that path? I could think about only the redirect by zabbix after the login is wrong.

Comment: @Geilmaker Yes, that's correct, but I suspect redirecting to ```/zabbix``` subdirectory like what I did is somehow wrong. Is there any conventional way to make a site serve from a specific subdirectory?

Comment: What do you mean by redirecting? The conventional way to make specific content to be served from a specific subdirectory is exactly what you done above. Define a location with `location /xxx` and inside that block declare what should get served by that. With your line `try_files       $uri $uri/ index.php;` you tell nginx to look at the defined `root` (in your case its defined in server scope, you can also declare it in location scope) and just serve the file/folder you find. If nothing is found just serve the `index.php`.